# An Excel Macro that will delete rows if certain values exist in a cell, then will concatenate?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I can't seem to piece together VBA code that will delete a row if certain strings exist in a cell. I can easily do it for only one, but can't figure out how to include multiple strings.

I've got the last part down, which is easy, just applying a concatenate formula to a range, but I have tried many things to get the first part right and nothing works.

Below is what I have hacked together and it will only work to delete rows if ONE particular string is in them "None". I need to also delete rows if the words "Subtotal", "Estimate, and "Empty" are in the cell.

```
With Sheets("Customer Copy")
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
    With .Cells(Lrow, "B")
    If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                If .Value = "None" Then .EntireRow.Delete

    End If

        End With

    Next Lrow

End With

    Worksheets("Customer Copy").Range("A1:A200").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(B1, D1, E1)"
```

Thank you for any help!!!

Comment: How about `If .Value = "None" or .Value = "Subtotal" or .Value = "Estimate" or .Value = "Empty" Then .EntireRow.Delete`?

Comment: You are absolutely right, sir! :) Thank you so much. I will also try the suggestions given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would work

```
If .Value = "None" or .Value = "Subtotal" or .Value = "Estimate" or .Value = "Empty" Then
```

Comment: You are right! I feel so silly. Thank you for answering

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, this is a good example for `Select Case`:

```
Select Case Trim(LCase(.Value))
    Case "none", "subtotal", "estimate", "empty":  .EntireRow.Delete
End Select
```

Comment: *(+1)* I like your solution most because it also handles invisible blanks before or after the string (which is often a source of trouble) and UPPER / lower case comparisons. Finally, you got all strings neatly combined together. Like this the OP can easily expand upon the strings he/she wishes to search for. The only thing I am not a big fan of is the `:` as it easily clogs the code and renders it less legible. But that's just personal flavor / preference I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add all the condition in if like below

```
If .Value = "None" Or .Value = "Subtotal" Or .Value = "Estimate" Or .Value = "Empty"  Then .EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Absolutely right and works perfectly! Cannot believe I didn't figure this out earlier!